# Generated files deleted when first running bin/magento

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2

Bit of a wierd one this and haven't got the bottom of it yet, nor have I seen it before.  So I'm setting up the prod server of a new store and when deploying to the server, the first time `bin/magento` is run, even without any arguments, just `bin/magento` on it's own, everything under `generated/code` and `generated/metadata` gets deleted.  Worth noting that with all further runs of `bin/magento` the files aren't deleted.  I'm using deployer.org to deploy which isn't relevant apart from that it makes releases for each deployment so I believe that as far as Magento is concerned when `bin/magento` is run after a simple `git clone` and then `composer install` it's the first time the command has been run.  The config in `env.php` sets the mode to production

Can anyone shed any light on what is going on exactly?  I have deployed plenty with a closely equivalent method for other stores and never come across this oddity.  I also can't seem to find any examples of tickets, threads etc of others having this same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully useful to others who may come across the same issue, but I've managed to track down the issue.  The culprit is the `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` module.  This module has a method `MagentoHackathon\Composer\Magento\Plugin::requestRegeneration()` which creates the empty file `var/.regenerate`.  This method is called in 2 other plugin methods in the class being `onPackageUnistall()` and `onNewCodeEvent()`.

The reason the files get deleted is because every time the object manager is instantiated in `Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManagerFactory::create()` there is a call to `Magento\Framework\Code\GeneratedFiles::cleanGeneratedFiles()`.  This method checks for the existence of the file `var/.regenerate` and if it exists the `generated/code`, `generated/metadata` and `var/cache` directories are cleared.  After this the method then deletes the `var/.regenerate` file hence the problem only showing itself on 'first run'.

I can understand the principle behind the `magento-hackathon/magento-composer-installer` logic, but it's been badly implemented really and doesn't consider the use case of deployments to a new release directory, or even if the deploy mode is `production`.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting explanation. How did you actually solve this issue?

Comment: I created a custom maintenance page so requests don't even hit Magento when in maintenance mode (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/maint-mode.html#compman-trouble-maint-create) and then put the store in maintenance mode as composer install runs, disabled cron too as that can kick off a request doing the same thing and then deleted var/.regenerate before taking the store out of maintenance mode.